# excel VBA passing values through subs compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and I'm trying to make an excel macro that loops through a selected folder and the file tabs. It will then call another sub to copypaste certain cells. I got a compile error(procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name) when trying to pass through the values.

Part of the first sub

```
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        CommandButton5_Click strSourceSheet, strDestinationSheet
    Next sht
```

Second sub

```
Sub CommandButton5_Click(strSourceSheet As String, strDestinationSheet As String)
Dim strSourceSheet As String, strDestinationSheet As String, sourceData As String

strSourceSheet = "Sheet1"
strDestinationSheet = "Sheet1"

Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(1, "A") = Sheets(strSourceSheet).Cells(2, "A").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line cause error?

Comment: The `Click` event handler doesn't take any arguments. If this is intended to be a user defined `Sub`, you just need to rename it.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the "tabs" are called sheets. (or worksheets)
Folders (or directories) are file related and are completely different.

as per Comintern, I'd suggest that you rename sub 2 to something like this (give it a meaningful name):

```
CopySelectedCells(strSourceSheet As String, strDestinationSheet As String)
```

and then call that from sub 1.

If you have a button called CommandButton5 then you probably need to have a click event for it.  Create a third sub:

```
Sub CommandButton5_Click()

End Sub
```

Note on parameters:
you'll get further with your code if you set your parameters in sub 1 before you call sub 2
good luck.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the error is gone after I changed the sub name. However, nothing happens from the second sub when I execute the code. The "Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(1, "A") = Sheets(strSourceSheet).Cells(2, "A").Value" line does not do anything. I tested with a msgbox from second sub and it works fine. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: put a .value on the first one too, so  

    something.Value = sourceSomething.value

I'd also look at passing sht as the 1st param to the routine so you get data from each sheet. (that's why we put stuff in a loop - usually!)